# Explanation about Delayed_Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Looking for an explanation into the `delayed_job` gem.

I understand it schedules and keeps a list of tasks that need to be done, and that those tasks can be created via the active_job interface.

What I don't understand is what starts the `taskrunner` or whatever it is that starts going through the list of jobs in the delayed_job table. Am I able to use the `whenever` gem to do this and call it as a chron job? Or should I be using the `daemons` gem? If so, what is the difference between `daemons` gem and `whenever`?

I am just a bit confused in all of this.

Lastly, I use heroku for staging, and a vpn managed via capistrano. How would that play into this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `delayed_job` script for that It needs to be run as a separate process.

> `script/delayed_job` can be used to manage a background process which will start working off jobs.
>
> To do so, add `gem "daemons"` to your `Gemfile` and make sure you've run rails generate delayed_job.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs

For heroku, [see docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job)

You need to update the `Procfile` with:

```
worker: rake jobs:work
```